# Combining errors

Tags: error-propagation

I've got this tricky problem to solve. Hope somebody can help me.

Let's suppose I want to know the mean radius of the trees in a wood.
For each tree i I measure the radius at the top, at tha center and at the bottom, and i get 3 values with the systematic uncertain given by the resolution of my instrument (always the same):

$X^i_{bot}$ $X^i_{mid}$ $X^i_{top}$ $\Delta X_{sys}$

How do I combine the values and how o I get the errors?

My first approach was to combine the 3 measures statisticaly in order to get a mean $X^i$ and a st. deviation $\sigma$, and then add the systematic error.

$\Delta X^i = \sqrt{\sigma^2+\Delta X_{sys}}$

Then to combine the different trees I've made a mean of central values and combined the error with the formula

$\Delta X=\sqrt{\Sigma (\frac{\delta f}{\delta X_i} \Delta X_i)^2}$

But I don't think that wuold be correct.

Furtheremore, I don't only need the trees mean radius, but I need the mean radius of a ring of a tree of that forest, provided that each tree has a different number of rings $n^i$.

I really don't know how to make this last part.

Comment: Wouldn't  $\Delta X = \Delta X_{sys}\cdot\sqrt{n_m}$ where $n_m$ is the number of measurements (in this case, 3) be more appropriate? Unless, of course, you are multiplying your measured data in some fashion?

Comment: You mean the single tree's error or the error on the mean radius of the wood?

Comment: What kind of uncertainty do you assume for the systematic uncertainty ($\Delta X_{sys}$), the $\Delta$ indicates a 100% interval, however the last two equations you give are for 68% intervals?

Comment: I didn't think about that. Can I handle this difference using the 68% of $\Delta X_{sys}$ instead of $\Delta X_{sys}$?

Comment: $\Delta$ represents a $1\sigma$ deviation as often as a 100% confidence interval. In any event, the difference is only a factor of $\sqrt{12}$ for discretized sampling (a worthwhile exercise in and of itself). The problem is that you are inconsistent with using $\Delta X_\mathrm{sys}$. Is it a discretization error (a type of random error) due to a digital instrument's resolution (as claimed in the text), or is it a true systematic error varying from tree to tree but constant (and unknown) for all measurements for a given tree (as suggested by the use in equations)?

Comment: With $\Delta X_{sys}$ i mean the resolution of the instrument so a discretizzation error. I used in the equation in that way becausa I thought I should treat it as a systematic. I don't know how to combine discretizzation and statistic errors.